# Splitting data in file in Python

Tags: python, split, valueerror

```
class Student:

    def __init__(self, name, hours, qpoints):
        self.name = name
        self.hours = float(hours)
        self.qpoints = float(qpoints)

    def getName(self):
        return self.name

    def getHours(self):
        return self.hours

    def getQPoints(self):
        return self.qpoints

    def gpa(self):
        return self.qpoints/self.hours

def makeStudent(infoStr):

    name, hours, qpoints = infoStr.split("\t")


    return Student(name, hours, qpoints)

def main():
    fileName = input("Enter file name: ")
    infile = open(fileName, "r")

    best = makeStudent(infile.readline())

    for line in infile:
        s = makeStudent(line)
        if s.gpa() > best.gpa():
            best = s

    infile.close()

    print("The best student is:", best.getName())
    print("hours:", best.getHours())
    print("GPA:", best.gpa())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I want to read line from a text file, split it in by "\t" or "," so I can assign it to variables, and I get "ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1) in makeStudent(infoStr) function. File I use is written correctly, I get same error if I edit file and code to "," instead of "\t". Why is that happening? Edit: Issue was in skipping lines in text. Solved.

Comment: Probably the file isn't tab-delimited. Please show the traceback

Comment: why are you iterating over the file and calling `readline`.  just do one or the other…

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "gpa.py", line 44, in <module>
        main()
      File "gpa.py", line 30, in main
        best = makeStudent(infile.readline())
      File "gpa.py", line 22, in makeStudent
        name, hours, qpoints = infoStr.split("\t")
    ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)
There is traceback. And file is tab delimited, i tried with commas, and blank spaces as someone suggested instead of tab, but still didn't work

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Notice that you are already iterating over the file lines with the block starting in `for line in infile`, so there's no need to do `infile.readline()` within.

Also you could check your line format before sending it to your function (or checking the format in the fuction, whatever you prefer).

```
{truncated code}

# This loop will put on each iteration the next line of the file in the "line" var.
for line in infile:

    # You need two commas in your line to be able to split it in 3 values.
    if line.count(",") != 2:
        print("WARN: Invalid format in line: "+line)
        # Of course that you could implement some counter to identify
        # the problematic line location within the file...
        quit()

    s = makeStudent(line)
    if s.gpa() > best.gpa():
        best = s

{truncated code}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question

Comment: roganjosh, sorry I'm new, is not the question "Why is that happening?"

Comment: "Ensure you don't have x" never answers _why_ something is happening in any situation. "Why can I not see beyond the horizon?" --> "Ensure you're not on a flat Earth"

Comment: I was going to comment this on the question, but the system does not allow me to put comments on the question due to "low reputation" so I put it this an answer. I'm sorry.

Comment: @Aleksandar, I understand my answer is not appropriate as per roganjosh explained above. However, you should chech that your last line is not an empty line.
Also, as one of the comments on your questions, it's not correct to do a `for line in file` block and then within this block do a `file.readline()` as you will be skipping lines.

Comment: Don't apologise, there's no need :) I know your position; your best bet is to play a longer game and answer questions where you have a very good chance of being right. It's tough to get off the starting block. The python tag is very active so your advice is likely to be commented by others.

Comment: Mattux, that actualy fixed it... The issue was skipping lines. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Please edit your answer to explain why this is an issue. I cannot remove my downvote unless the answer is edited after I voted (the way SO voting works :( )

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the `infoStr` line may not contain the character you're splitting on (e.g. a blank line `''`). Wrap this in a try block and you should be fine.

```
try:
    name, hours, qpoints = infoStr.split('\t')
except ValueError:
    name, hours, qpoints = None, None, None
```

You'll then need to handle the `None` case before instantiating `Student`.

Comment: But that might drop data? The OP seems to have two delimiters, apparently, and only tests 1

Comment: why not put a `print(repr(infoStr))` in there and re`raise` the exception to help figure out what is causing the exception…

Comment: Yes that seems like a good idea, I just wanted to show the approach to handling exceptions.

Answer (score -1):

I bet this is a classic tabs vs. spaces problem. Your file might actually be space separated due to IDE formatting or search and replace going haywire.

Try this:

```
def makeStudent(infoStr):
    FAKE_TAB = '    '
    name, hours, qpoints = infoStr.split(FAKE_TAB)

    return Student(name, hours, qpoints)
```

If that doesn't work, determine how many spaces are between each value in each line manually and then replace FAKE_TAB with that. Admittedly, its a slightly sketchy patch...

Comment: Python would only throw an error if the number of spaces is different than the ones we declared in that var

Comment: Splitting by a comma works for me. Do you possibly have any empty lines in your file?